# How do i justify the limit of this sequence using the definition?

Tags: limits

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } \, S_n$ where

$$S_n = \frac{n^2 + 2n + 2}{n^2 + n}$$

I get that it converges to 1 but i dont get how you justify that using the definition:

A sequence {sn} converges to a limit s if for every epsilon > 0 there is an
integer N such that
|sn - s| < epsilon if n =< N

Comment: Hint: Divide throught by $n^2$ and note that any fraction with a constant nominator and a power of $n$ in the denominator, will tend to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|S_n - 1| = \dfrac{n+2}{n^2+n} < \dfrac{2}{n}< \varepsilon$, if $n> \left[\dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}\right]+1$.

Comment: hello, thanks for the help but apparently there was a typo in my original post. the 2 in the denominator should be n

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks. i understand everything except for the + 1 at the end. is that just to make sure that it will be less than epsilon?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=1+\frac2n-\frac1{n+1}\implies|S_n-1|\leqslant\frac2n$$